# Using "meteor mongo" on localhost but with remote Database

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteorite

I'm following the telescope tutorial.

1. I created a /client/collections/myfile.js
2. I'm on localhost, but I'm launching Meteor with remote DB hosted on MongoHQ instead of using Meteor's local DB.
3. In this tutorial I'm told to insert a new post by opening the Mongo console.

   ```
    $ meteor mongo
   ```

How can I:

```
$ meteor mongo (somehow connect to my remote DB to use the meteor commands in terminal
```

So that I can:

```
$ db.collectionname.insert({ stuff });
```

Or does this have nothing to do with "Meteor" in this case and I just use a Mongo shell outside of Meteor? The collection that I created in "/client/collections/collection.js" is this simply for telling Meteor which collection to push as a subset to the client?

I'd like to use the same DB ( remotely hosted with MongoHQ) for my localhost development, and my actual live dev.mysite.com so when I deploy to this dev site, anything I've done in the DB is also there and ready to go.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming you had a username of `username`, a password of `PASSWORD`, a database named `test`, and a hostname of `hatch.mongohq.com`:

#### Connecting via the shell

```
$ mongo hatch.mongohq.com:27017/test -u username -p PASSWORD
```

#### Connecting via Meteor

```
$ MONGO_URL="mongodb://username:PASSWORD@hatch.mongohq.com:27017/test" meteor
```

---

#### Other notes

1. You should define your Meteor collections outside of the `client` directory so they can be used on both the client and the server. See [this](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#where-should-i-put-my-files) for more details.
2. You will find that connecting to a remote database is much slower than connecting locally, so it's generally not recommended for development.
3. Meteor creates a dev database for you when it starts. This also affords you the very helpful commands: `meteor reset` and `meteor mongo`, to reset, and connect to said database.

---

#### Initializing your database

Create a file on the server for initialization - e.g. `server/initialize.js`. When the server starts you can add users or other documents which do not yet exist. For example:

```js
Meteor.startup(function() {
  if (Meteor.users.find().count() === 0) {
    Accounts.createUser({
      username: 'jsmith',
      password: 'password',
      profile: {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Smith'
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks David. Here is a use-case scenario that I just can't get my head around: I want to create security roles and store them in the DB ( Admin, Moderator, etc. ) and then assign those roles to specific users. Dealing with a local DB instance, vs. a remote DB, I'm just a little lost as to how to make this happen.

Comment: Is there where I would make use of fixtures? Creating the accounts and roles when the server starts if they don't exist?

Comment: I'm glad to be of help. I'd also recommend looking at the [roles](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles) package.