# How do I set up mongodb to be accessed remotely via URI?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, digital-ocean

I'm trying to set up a MongoDB instance running on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu 14.x server. What I need to do is generate a URI that looks like

mongodb://username:password@myserver.com:12345/db_name

that I can use to access from outside services I create. How do I configure my mongodb instance so there's a URI available that can be accessed remotely from anywhere if needed? It needs to have the username and password in the URI so there's some security still.

Comment: are you using mupx or mup to deploy into DO?

Comment: @traviswingo Is this a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054856/using-meteor-mongo-on-localhost-but-with-remote-mongodb)?

Comment: @DavidWeldon it is not. I want to know how to create that URI and set up the username and password.

Comment: Oh I see. You may want to skip all the info about mongolab in your question and just ask something like "how do I set up my own mongodb instance for user with meteor?". What you really want is to set up mongo with a replica set so you have tail the oplog - otherwise your performance will be terrible. Just google for `meteor set up mongodb and replica sets` and read the top few posts.

Comment: Hm this is interesting and I will look into it, but that doesn't necessarily answer the question at hand. What I'm trying to do is create and obtain a URI, just like what MongoLab provides, but have it on my own server instead. I don't know what this entails. It just needs to look like mongodb://username:password@myserver.com:12345/db_name so I can access it from any service I create whether or not they are on the same server.

Comment: @DavidWeldon I re-wrote my question to be better directed at my issue. Thanks for helping out, I'll look into replica sets once I figure out how to set everything up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use similar uri to remotely access mongoldb set up on your own server. For that uri will be

mongodb://username:password@ip_address_of_server:port_no/db_name

Comment: I don't know what the username:password is on my server. My question is how to set up the username:password in order to use that URI remotely.

Comment: You can go through this link. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/